# Defining page layout for defualt post formats (aside)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

single-aside.php defined but still using single.php for my post that having aside format.

Hi i used post-formats(aside) for some of my post and using single.php for styling them in the past despite defining a new post-type , the problem is now i want to use another page layout diffrent than my other posts and pages just for this aside type , but when i create single-aside.php wordpress doesnt use this page , and i flushed away my permalinks thats not the problem. do you think single page is defineable for defualt post formats like aside, video,quote and... ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you can use `has_post_format()` see more here https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats under Using Formats.

Since the post formats aren't custom post types, you would need to add it to `single.php`:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' )) {
  //Your custom code for aside goes here
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to use a different php file, you can create your custom post type and give support for Post formats.

Register with support:

```
add_action( 'init', 'aside_post_type' );
function aside_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'aside',
      array(
        'labels' => array( 'name' => __( 'Aside' ) ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats') //this will give support for post formats
    )
  );
}
```

Then add `single-aside.php` to your theme and style this custom post type as needed.